# Using xargs to create a remote directory

Tags: directory, pipe, xargs

I want to use the xargs command to read the standard output from my date command. The following pipe works, creating a directory "2019-12-03" in the current directory.

```
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -r ../IDNumber/IDNumber.txt | xargs mkdir
```

What I would like it to do, however, is use the standard output from the data command to make a directory in a remote location, username@archivalstorage.university.edu:/remote/folder/path/, resulting in username@archivalstorage.university.edu:/remote/folder/path/2019-12-03.

Running the following command:

```
date "+%Y-%m-%d" -r ../IDNumber/IDNumber.txt | xargs mkdir -p username@archivalstorage.university.edu:/remote/folder/path/
```

This command does not give any kind of error, but no folder is actually created in the remote location I have specified.

Answer (score 0):

`mkdir` doesn't support the remote directory. Use ssh instead, with [command substitute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution):

```
ssh user@host 'cd /path/to/dir && mkdir `date +%Y-%m-%d`'
```

or with xargs:

```
date +%Y-%m-%d | xargs -I _ ssh user@host 'cd /tmp && mkdir _'
```

Comment: That works very well! Unfortunately the user in user@host involves the _ symbol and adds the date there. Is there a character to add before special characters like that to prevent the bash scripts from reading it as part of the command? Or is it possible to use a different symbol other than _? Thank you!